# Swift compiler (dictionary key): "must conform to Hashable" and "cannot conform to Hashable". Huh?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift-protocols, any, hashable

I feel like the Swift compiler is giving me mixed messages.
I don't understand what the issue is.

This is what I have, and I want those enum to be keys to a dictionary:

```
protocol ArbitraryKey : CaseIterable, Hashable {}
enum HearNoEvil  : ArbitraryKey { case a, b, c }
enum SeeNoEvil   : ArbitraryKey { case d, e, f }
enum SpeakNoEvil : ArbitraryKey { case g, h, i }
```

This is what I want to *avoid*:

```
var dictionary : [ AnyHashable : String ] = [:]
```

This is what I want to do:

```
var dictionary : [ any ArbitraryKey : String ] = [:]
```

The protocol `ArbitraryKey` will eventually have methods I want to be able to invoke on the enums values.

However, the iOS 16.4 / Swift 5.7+ compiler objects to everything I've tried:

---

***If  I  do  this:***

```
protocol ArbitraryKey : CaseIterable, Hashable {}
var dictonary : [ArbitraryKey : String] = [:]
```

```
    Type 'any ArbitraryKey' cannot conform to 'Hashable'
    Use of protocol 'ArbitraryKey' as a type must be written 'any ArbitraryKey'
    Replace 'ArbitraryKey' with 'any ArbitraryKey'
```

---

***So  I  "fix"  it:***

```
protocol ArbitraryKey : CaseIterable, Hashable {}
var dictonary : [any ArbitraryKey : String] = [:]  // <-- added 'any'
```

```
     Type 'any ArbitraryKey' cannot conform to 'Hashable'
```

---

***So  I  "fix"  that:***

```
protocol ArbitraryKey : CaseIterable {}  // <-- removed Hashable
var dictonary : [any ArbitraryKey : String] = [:]
```

```
     Type 'any ArbitraryKey' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

---

In conclusion:
At this point the chump is stumped.
Can someone explain what is going on?
Any thoughts on a different approach that's clean and straightforward?

Comment: A protocol cannot conform to a protocol. The only thing that can go in the "key" slot in a dictionary declaration is the name of a real type, not an existential (protocol).

Comment: @matt, but I've had this in the code forever: `protocol ArbitraryKey : CaseIterable, Hashable {}` and it worked fine. Just not as a Dictionary key.

Comment: That is exactly what I just said.

Comment: @matt: Is there a way to say it differently so a stupid person (like I'm feeling) could understand?

Comment: In `[Foo: Bar]` you are resolving the Key and Value generic placeholders. Only the name of a concrete type can do that. For Key it must additionally be the name of a concrete type that adopts Hashable. A protocol is not that. That is exactly why Swift 5.8 forces you to say `any`, so that you are brought face to face with the facts.

Comment: Remarkably similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851946/swift-protocol-x-as-a-type-cannot-conform-to-hashable

Comment: Anyway so the answer to the question posed in your title is that the compiler is saying very clearly, What goes here must be a type that conforms to Hashable, and a protocol existential cannot conform to Hashable so it cannot go here.

Comment: @matt, sadly though, enum is Hashable IIRC and a concrete type, and yet besides protocol, I can't find a way to unify a various enums around a theme of some sort (like inheritance). So it just complicates coding all over the place. Unless there's something else I'm not aware of. I want to index that dictionary with any of a few kinds of enums, which are concrete, in other words

Comment: No you cannot "unify a various enums around a theme of some sort" with inheritance. How about creating a concrete type `AnyArbitraryKey` and use that as the key type? This is kind of like `AnyHashable`, but only types conforming to `ArbitraryKey` can be converted to `AnyArbitraryKey`.

Comment: @Sweeper the problem is, the way I'm doing it, I pull keys out of the dictionary as AnyHashable and have to cast them back into their original enum types with overhead, and until I do so, I can't access the protocol methods in common to all the keys, because they're AnyHashable. I guess I might be able to work something out with what you mentioned.

Comment: Just to add a bit of clarification as to _why_ this doesn't work: when you write out `any ArbitraryKey`, you are declaring a "box" of sorts, which can _hold_ anything which conforms to `ArbitraryKey`. Although the values inside of the box may be `Hashable`, the _box itself_ isn't, which is why it can't be used in this way. There are contexts where you can hold a box just fine, but the box can't conform to any protocols. This is something the language (and the compiler diagnostics) doesn't make very clear, sadly.

Comment: Okay, the fact that you are "pulling keys out" of the dictionary like this makes me highly suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you show how you intend on using the dictionary, what kind of methods are in `ArbitraryKey`, and why you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper, well... it's not exactly bait & switch... Yes I had an agenda that led to error messages that confused me. Having found it's a dead end, I'm looking for another way to accomplish the agenda.  Wasn't due to reckless omissions.  SO's bot will frown on dragging out in comments . Methods are getters, maybe red herring. Prob is I have distinct key types I need to keep distinct and I want dictionary keyed with any of them, as they are fundamentally similar yet slightly distinct. Intricate & 50K lines of code might preclude big retrofit.

Comment: I really think the actual question about what the compiler is saying has been answered. It's not contradicting itself, it's saying something definite and clear. To do what you're asking to do will require type erasure.

Comment: ty @matt definitely looks like the topic of interest. Coming up to speed on it now through various online write-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to make a dictionary where the keys are restricted to the types (enums in your example) which conform to a specific protocol, I can think of creating a specific dict for the protocol.

```
protocol P1: Hashable {}

struct P1KeyDict<Value> {
    private var items: [AnyHashable: Value] = [:]
    
    subscript<K:P1>(key: K) -> Value {
        get {
            return items[key as AnyHashable]!
        }
        set {
            items[key as AnyHashable] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Here's How to Use:

```
var dict: P1KeyDict<String> = P1KeyDict()

enum E1: P1 { case a, b, c }
enum E2: P1 { case d, e, f }
enum E3 { case g, h, i } // for Testing a Type not conforming to the protocol


dict[E1.a] = "Hello"
dict[E2.f] = "World"

print(dict[E1.a])
print(dict[E2.f])

dict[E3.h] = "Good"     // Compile-time Error as Expected:
                        // Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'E3' conform to 'P1'
```

This also works for types other than enum e.g. struct, but there is a caveat:
If AnyHashable(obj1) and AnyHashable(obj2) are the same, it leads to the same key which may be not what you want. For that case, you can implement a hashing method other than just using AnyHashable.

Comment: This looks like what I've been reading is called 'boxing'. Also a kind of Swift "type erasure" which @matt mentioned, which I'm starting to come up to speed on now: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/different-flavors-of-type-erasure-in-swift/   Your use of Swift's preferred 'struct' over 'class' and the subscript method are good so I'll select your answer, even though matt provided essentially that and more, but  he will probably not miss the rep. gain ;-).

Answer (score 1):

The basic question you're asking in your title is how the compile errors "must conform to Hashable" and "cannot conform to Hashable" can be compatible. They are not just compatible; they are the same.

As I've explained to you in a comment, when you declare a dictionary as being of type `[Foo: Bar]`, you are resolving the Key and Value generic placeholders. *Only the name of a concrete type can do that.* And for Key the type name that you put must additionally be the name of a concrete type that adopts Hashable.

Well, a protocol is not that. It isn't a concrete type, and it cannot conform to Hashable (protocols cannot conform to protocols). Indeed, that is exactly why Swift 5.8 forces you to say `any`, so that you are brought face to face with the facts. When the compiler makes you say `any MyProtocol` it is trying to make you understand that this is an *existential*, not a concrete type.

Anyway so the answer to the question posed in your title is that the compiler is saying very clearly, "What goes here must be a type that conforms to Hashable, and a protocol existential *cannot* conform to Hashable so it cannot go here."

With regard to your comment:

> I want to index that dictionary with any of a few kinds of enums, which are concrete

Okay, well, that seems to me to be a silly thing to want to do, but the point is, if you were to do that, you would *not* be able to do it by making any sort of type declaration of the Key type of your dictionary, for the reasons I've just demonstrated. You would need to perform some sort of type erasure.

For example, you could *hide* from the dictionary the fact that all its keys enums that conform to a certain protocol, by making that fact something that *you* know rather than trying to make the dictionary know it. To do so, you might just wrap the dictionary in a class that guards the doors so that the only acceptable keys are types that conform to your protocol. Like this:

```
protocol ArbitraryKey : CaseIterable, Hashable {}
enum HearNoEvil  : ArbitraryKey { case a, b, c }
enum SeeNoEvil   : ArbitraryKey { case d, e, f }
enum SpeakNoEvil : ArbitraryKey { case g, h, i }

class DictionaryWrapper {
    var dict = [AnyHashable: String]()
    func setKey<T: ArbitraryKey>(_ key: T, toValue value: String) {
        dict[key] = value
    }
    func getValueForKey<T: ArbitraryKey>(_ key: T) -> String? {
        return dict[key]
    }
}
```

That may seem rather silly, and indeed it is; and it's only an example. But it does succeed very simply in doing what you have (for reasons known only to you) asked to do: We have guaranteed *to the caller of our code* (such as `setKey` and `getValueForKey` that this key is a type that conforms to the ArbitraryKey protocol. So you could just go on writing methods for our DictionaryWrapper until you've accomplished whatever your ultimate goal is.

---

<sub>[**Extra Point:**] I think part of the confusion here is in the grasp of the meaning of expressions such as `protocol ArbitraryKey : Hashable {}`. You asked about this in a comment, in a way that made me think you think this means that ArbitraryKey conforms to Hashable. It doesn't. Protocols don't conform to protocols. That code is talking about the *concrete* type that will conform to *this* protocol (ArbitraryKey). It says: "To conform to me, you must *also* (in addition to any requirements that I may impose) conform to Hashable." It isn't a statement about what the protocol does, it's a statement about what the conforming type has to do in order to conform.</sub>

Comment: Again, grateful for the info.  Not sure why my approach is inherently absurd unless I'm unaware of a des. patt. or compsci principle. Overall my approach using AnyHashable, let's say typealias AnimalKey = AnyHashable, has worked well, but prob more type-conversion around the proj than ideal? I see value having various enum types`enum Otters`, `enum Squirrels`, `enum Tigers`, that conform to CaseIterable and String, enumerate with `.map` and `.forEach`  in a succinct fashion, which can be looked-up  in a dictionary.  Boxing, or wrapping the dictionary could provide multiple advantages tho.

Comment: I was less familiar with Swift when I started this project a year ago, and committed the code around that approach. But the retrofit may not be so bad. I don't even really need to do it. I just realized that if I added some methods to to the enums that I could simplify certain tasks, but this makes me think that boxing could solve even that problem better.

Comment: Boxing is what I'm doing here. Basically the answer you've accepted is just the same as what I've suggested here. Nothing wrong with that! I'm just making sure you understand they are effectively identical.